# react js is getting Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

i am beginner in reactjs. i am getting map error in higher order component. when i try to  `console.log(items)` the items is showing in console log but items are not rendering in template can anybody tell me how can i solve the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        items: result.items
                    });
                }
            )
    }

    render() {
        const { items } = this.state;

        return (
            <ul>
                {items.map(item => (
                    <li key={item.id}>
                        {item.name} {item.price}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        );

    }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/` returns an array already so you just need to make the following change:

```js
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        items: result // just return result               
                    });
                }
            )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the payload of the endpoint. It looks like:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  },
  // ...
```

The `result` argument is a plain array; it's not an object with an `items` property. Use:

```
this.setState({
  items: result
});
```

The items don't have `price` properties either. Choose either `userId`, `id`, `title`, or `completed`.

Answer (score 1):

i'm pretty sure that in this code:

```
 this.setState({ items: result.items});
```

`result.items` is not an array or what you expect, i suggest to log the `result` and check that is an array